# How to implement .SCSS on my own website?

Tags: html, css, web, sass

I've been experimenting on Codepen just recently and I was wondering how I could implement the code that is displayed on the website on one of my own. I realized that most of the formats used on Codepen aren't pure ".css". I learned it's something new called ".scss". I was wondering where to start and if anybody could help me out in understanding how .scss works. Especially [This](http://codepen.io/chuckneely/pen/ronfx)

```
body{
  background:black;
  font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
}

.glitch{
  color:white;
  font-size:0px;
  position:relative;
  width:268px;
  height:654px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-indent:-999em;
  background:transparent url(http://cdn.hiphopwired.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Vanellope-Von-Scweetz-wreck-it-ralph.png) center center no-repeat;
}
@keyframes noise-anim{
  $steps:20;
  @for $i from 0 through $steps{
    #{percentage($i*(1/$steps))}{
      clip:rect(random(654)+px,9999px,random(654)+px,0);
    }
  }
}
.glitch:after{
  content:'';
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:2px;
  top:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  clip:rect(0,900px,0,0); 
  animation:noise-anim 2s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
  background:inherit;
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
}

@keyframes noise-anim-2{
  $steps:20;
  @for $i from 0 through $steps{
    #{percentage($i*(1/$steps))}{
      clip:rect(random(100)+px,9999px,random(100)+px,0);
    }
  }
}

.glitch:before{
  content: '';
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:-2px;
  top:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  clip:rect(0,900px,0,0); 
  animation:noise-anim-2 3s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
  background:inherit;
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(300deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(300deg);
}
```

Comment: http://www.sass-lang.com. It's not something you can include directly, you have to compile it down to CSS.

Comment: How can that be done?

Comment: @kotAPI — Maybe the link Jon posted explains…

Comment: @Quentin Jon has deleted the comment I suppose? I can't find it now. 
Also I tried with the code that Jon posted and the glitch effect doesn't show on my website when I try to run it. I can't seem to figure out why.

I'm just trying to make an image glitch, do you have any solution that you can think of?

Comment: @kotAPI — No, the comment has not been deleted: http://note.io/1G0NW8i

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I had to refresh my page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### SASS is still CSS

Okay, to make things straight - all you see is still CSS, but it was written in SASS then compiled back to CSS.

SASS is like "CSS on steroids" where you can use loops, mixins and tons of cool stuff. You write in SASS, then compile it to CSS and here you are.

### Getting & understanding SASS

To get you going you have to install SASS from http://sass-lang.com/install, if you're not familiar with command line you can install a separate app such as [Scout](http://mhs.github.io/scout-app/) or [Koala](http://koala-app.com) (there's more on sass-lang install page).

Then you basically set the application/sass to track file x (SASS) and output what you write to file y (CSS), every time you change something in file x it's getting recompiled and moved to y.

You will have to learn SASS syntax though, but it's quite clear and easy if you already know CSS IMHO.

To confuse you more, there's also [Compass](http://compass-style.org/install/) which is a very cool framework based on SASS, you should definitely give it a go once you get a grip of SASS.

### Your animation explained

About your second question - the example provided is just a simple [CSS3 animation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) using `@keyframes` and `animation` You can do this in css-only and you don't need SASS for that.

Here's a proof your example is basically some CSS code: http://jsfiddle.net/ypq7aost/ (note it's pure CSS!)

Comment: Hello Bart, I've tried using the code generated from the link and I've just saved changes, When I refreshed my webpage. I see the image but the glitch effect doesn't show. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Because CSS3 animations still need to use prefixes, try adding `<script type='text/javascript' src="http://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/prefixfree.min.js"></script>` to your documents head section . Here's up-to-date list of stuff that needs prefixes (check the animations tab): http://shouldiprefix.com . One day you won't need prefixes for animations, but at this moment - you do. You can do them manually or include prefixfree.min.js on your pages, you can get it at: http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it would be this complex. It seems you might be right about this. I will try and figure my way around it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

.scss code is code written in SASS, basically an extension of CSS.

See http://sass-lang.com/install for more information and help on how to install, but I will start you off below...

Sass is a Ruby gem, so you'll need to have ruby installed to install SASS (get ruby [here](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/)) Once you have this installed, simply run `gem install sass` in your terminal (e.g. command line for windows.)

You can do this by typing sass `--watch sass_folder:stylesheets_folder` where sass_folder is the folder of where your sass files are kept (file extensions must be .sass) and stylesheets_folder is your output folder.
Adding --watch to it means it will watch the folder for any further changes and compile them as soon as you save them.

Good luck.